# Why does 'out of bounds' indexing differ between a matrix and a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, subset

I'm sure this is kind of basic, but I'd just like to *really* understand the logic of R data structures here.

If I subset a matrix by index out of bounds, I get exactly that error:

```
m <- matrix(data = c("foo", "bar"), nrow = 1)
m[2,]
# Error in m[2, ] : subscript out of bounds
```

If I do the same do a data frame, however, I get *all `NA` rows*:

```
df <- data.frame(foo = "foo", bar = "bar")
df[2,]
#    foo  bar
# NA <NA> <NA>
```

If I subset into a non-existent data frame *column* I get the familiar

```
df[, 3]
# Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , 3) : undefined columns selected
```

I know (roughly) that data frame rows are weird and to be treated carefully, but I don't quite see the connection to the above behavior.

Can someone explain *why* R behaves in this way for non-existent df rows?

**Update**

To be sure, giving `NA` on out-of-bounds subsets, is *normal* R behavior for 1D vectors:

```
vec <- c("foo", "bar")
vec[3]
# [1] NA
```

So in a way, the *weird one out* here is *matrix* subsetting, not dataframe subsetting, depending from where you're starting out.
Still the different 2D subsetting behavior (`m[2, ]` vs `df[2, ]`) might strike a dense user (as I am right now) as inconsistent.

Comment: Regarding  "*I know (roughly) that data frame rows are weird and to be treated carefully*", this is because data frames are heterogeneous (i.e. you can store different formats in different columns), thus they can not be considered as vectors by default and need to be treated ...well...carefully. As far as the indexing goes, I m not sure. Interesting to find out why though

Comment: Same with lists. Create a list `l1 <- list('foo', 'bar')`. Now try the following: **1)** `l1[3]`, **2)** `l1[[3]]`

Comment: Maybe atomic vector or a similar object of atomic nature give rise to this peculiarity. `is.atomic(a_matrix)` yields `TRUE` while for a list or a data.frame this condition is not satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone explain why R behaves in this way[?]

Short answer: No, probably not.

---

Longer answer:
Once upon a time I was thinking about something similar and read this thread on R-devel: [Definition of `[[`](https://mailman.stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2009-March/052626.html). Basically it boils down to:

> The semantics of `[` and `[[` don't seem to be fully specified in the [Reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Indexing). [...] I assume that these are features, not bugs, but I can't find documentation for them

Duncan Murdoch, a former member of the R core team gives a very nice [reply](https://mailman.stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2009-March/052628.html):

> There is more documentation in the man page for `Extract`, but I think it is incomplete. The most complete documentation is of course the source code*, but *it may not answer the question of what's intentional and what's accidental*

As mentioned in the R-devel thread, the only description in the manual is [3.4.1 Indexing by vectors](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Indexing):

> If `i` is positive and exceeds `length(x)` then the corresponding selection is `NA`

But, this applies to "indexing of simple vectors". Similar out of bounds indexing for "non-simple" vectors does not seem to be described. Duncan Murdoch again:

> So what is a simple vector?  That is not explicitly defined, and it probably should be.

Thus, it may seem like no one knows the answer to your *why* question.

---

See also "8.2.13 nonexistent value in subscript" in the excellent [R Inferno by Patrick Burns](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), and the section "Missing/out of bounds indices" in [Hadley's book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#subsetting-operators).

---

*Source code for the [`[` subset operator](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/subset.c#L639). A search for `R_MSG_subs_o_b` (which corresponds to error message ["subscript out of bounds"](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/include/Errormsg.h#L27)) provides no obvious clue why OOB `[` indexing of matrices and when using `[[` give an error, whereas OOB `[` indexing of "simple vectors" results in `NA`.