# Select data frame rows with non-existent indices: how to make it fail

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Is there a way to make row indexing of a `data.frame` to be strict and fail or throw exception (condition in R) on attempt to access non-existent index?

A small example:

```
df = data.frame(foo = c(1))
df
#   foo
# 1   1
```

When selecting *rows* using non-existent indices, `NA` is returned:

```
df[c("a", "b", "c"), ]
# [1] NA NA NA
```

However, I want it to *fail* for non-existent row indices, similar to how it fails for non-existent columns:

```
df[ , c("a", "b", "c")]
# Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , c("a", "b", "c")) : 
#   undefined columns selected
```

Comment: You can create a function to return the error i.e something like `f1 <- function(dat, ind){stopifnot(all(ind %in% row.names(dat)))}`

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a strict mode that affect all user executed code without modifications. I think this is bizarre to return NA for non existent index.
In contrast pandas df.loc raise KeyError and df.iloc raise IndexError.

Comment: In `data.table`, `integer` and `logical` vectors in `i` currently work the same way as in `[.data.frame`. However, ["there is PR #4353 already for .. `nomatch=NULL` .. likely to be available in next CRAN release"](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4375#issuecomment-612609686). A `character` vector, like in your example, may cause an error in `data.table`: "When `i` is a [...] character vector, the columns to join by must be specified using `on=` argument [...], by keying `x` [...], or by sharing column names between `x` and `i`."

Comment: @Henrik That's great that data.table going to supports this. Can this be enabled as flag?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean by "_Can this be enabled as flag?_ You may be interested in a related post: I once answered a question on [_why_ out-of-bounds indexing differs between matrix and data.frame.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53448128/why-does-out-of-bounds-indexing-differ-between-a-matrix-and-a-data-frame). I found it quite interesting that no one seemed to know and how vaguely it is described in the docs :)

Comment: @Henrik Thanks! Interesting answer of yours in that related link.
I think that *The semantics of [ and [[ don't seem to be fully specified in the Reference manual* - is a facepalm.